# Calculating value of a cryptocurrency portfolio

Tags: currency, cryptocurrency

If I have a number of different cryptocurrencies and their current exchange rate in both bitcoin and USD, would this be true?

`portfolio balance in bitcoin == portfolio balance in USD / bitcoin to USD exchange rate`

The reason I ask is that I am doing this calculation on a current portfolio and these two values don't match.

Answer (score 4):

watch the fraction:

```
portfolio balance in bitcoin == portfolio balance in USD / bitcoin to USD exchange rate
```

the units should be

```
bitcoins = dollars x (bitcoins/dollars)
```

this way the dollars cancel out.

Comment: Or `B = $ / ($ / B)`, if `$ / B` is the more easily accessible number.